# Deploying a Java flexible project by Google Cloud maven plugin to a different region

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have a simple servlet Java project which I intend to deploy to App Engine southeast asia region.

I am using:

```
mvn gcloud:deploy
```

But it always deploys it to us-central region, what about if I want to deploy to a different region?

Answer (score 1):

The region where your servlet is deployed is the one selected during the [App Engine creation process](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app/creating-your-application#before_you_begin). I'm guessing that you selected `us-central` at that time. That's why you are deploying to that region.

Currently, you [can't change the App Engine's region](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) after you set it the first time. So, if you want to deploy to a different version, you'll have to create a new project, create a new App Engine and then select other region.

There are various feature requests in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) regarding changing App Engine's zone after creation, [like this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36878762), and the App Engine developer team is aware of this petitions, so the situation migh change in the future.